# Shared iAd Banner doesn't appear between TableViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, iad

Based on the tutorial at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5XcVnHCQ0w , I implemented shared iAd banner view to show between header position of two tables. Two table controllers are under navigation controller. Banner view is showing in the first table, but it is not showing in the next table.

Same code I implemented in UItableViewControllers

```
     - (AppDelegate *) appdelegate {
        return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    }

     -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
      return 100.0;
    }

    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        _UIiAD = [[self appdelegate] UIiAD];
        _UIiAD.delegate = self;

        [_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(0,21,320,50)];
        [self.view addSubview:_UIiAD];
    }

    -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
        _UIiAD.delegate = nil;
        _UIiAD=nil;
        [_UIiAD removeFromSuperview];
    }

    -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
        NSLog(@"ads loaded");
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [_UIiAD setAlpha:1];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    -(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
        NSLog(@"ads not loaded");
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [_UIiAD setAlpha:0];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```